# Compile error for datatype mismatch

Tags: apex, class

Friends, I am getting below error on this line:

```
 if(dt.start_date_oapi__c.month()== todaydate.month() && dt.Year_OAPI__c == todaydate.year()){
            dt.RecordTypeId = recordtypeforEndoftheMonth.get(FirstdayRecordtype.toUpperCase());
            dt.Active_OAPI__c = true;
            dts.add(dt);
         }
```

Error: Compile Error: Comparison arguments must be compatible types: String, Integer at line 39 column 71

Can someone suggest me what to do?

Comment: I guess your field `dt.Year_OAPI__c` is of type String? If that's the case, then try `Integer.valueOf(dt.Year_OAPI__c) == todaydate.year()`

Comment: ... or `dt.Year_OAPI__c == String.valueOf(todaydate.year())` might be a little safer if the Year_OAPI__c field doesn't always contain a valid integer. (Or change the type of the Year_OAPI__c field to be a number.)